# Simplifying the product of $(x-x_j)$'s when $x_k$ has multiplicty $\geq 2$

Tags: solution-verification, products, index-notation

Let $w(x)$ be defined as such: $w(x) = \prod_{j=0}^{n}(x-x_j)$, where $x_j$'s are distinct real numbers, $j=0,1,...,n$.

Suppose there exists exactly one point $x_k$, $k \in {0,1,...,n}$ such that $x_k$ has multiplicity $\geq 2$. I mean that it's given that the other points have multiplicity $1$.

Can we rewrite the product as $w(x) = (x-x_k)^2\prod_{j=0, j\neq k}^{n}(x-x_j)$?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @Semiclassical although writing it like this correctly reflects the multiplicity of $x_k$, why is this allowed? The product notation doesn't 'instruct' one to square any of the multiplicands right?

Comment: The restriction $j\neq k$ means that the product doesn't include the factor $x-x_k$. The squaring is provided by hand with the factor $(x-x_k)^2$ in front.

Comment: @Semiclassical "provided by hand" the notation doesn't dictate that though, is that correct? So you are invoking an additional step there. I'm trying to understand the rules that govern this step more clearly

Answer (score 0):

No, there is something wrong. If $x_k$ is of multiplicity at least two, this means there is some other index, say $x_\ell$ for which $x_k=x_\ell$. Which contradicts the assumption that $x_k$ is the only one of multiplicity 2.

If $x_k$ has multiplicity at leats 2, then the product can be written as
$$w(x)=(x-x_k)(x-x_\ell)\prod_{j=0, j\neq k, j\neq \ell}^{n}(x-x_j),$$
or
$$w(x)=(x-x_k)^2\prod_{j=0, j\neq k, j\neq \ell}^{n}(x-x_j),$$

Comment: I think there's a mistake in your approach. $x_j$'s are distinct by assumption.

Comment: Maybe, however there is something I don't understand. If if all $x_j$'s are different, I don't see how $x_k$ can have multiplicity 2. I think that you cannot have both conditions satisfied. There is maybe something I don't understand, so maybe you could provide an example with fixed $n$, different $x_i$'s, and exactly one $x_k$ having multiplicity 2.

Comment: Consider the polynomial $w(x)=(x-x_0)^2(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$. Then $x_0,$ $x_1,$ and $x_2$ are all roots of $w(x)$. However, only one $x_i$ has multiplicity $2$. Namely, $x_0$. Take $x_0 = 1$, $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 3$. These $x_i$'s are distinct.

Comment: But then the first paragraph in your question is false, where you require that $w(x)=\prod(x-x_j)$ where all of $x_j$ are different. While in the example you have linear factorization of $w=(x-x_0)(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ where two of the linear factors are clearly equal.

Comment: these are $3$ distinct points $x_0, x_1, x_2$. One of them appears twice because it has multiplicity two. That is not the same as saying $x_0 = x_i$ for some $i \neq 0$ - *that* would be considered non-distinct

Comment: To clarify the first paragraph can be rephrased: let $w(x)=\prod_{j=0}^n(x-x_j)$, $j=0,1,...,n$, where $x_i = x_j$ implies $i = j$. Thus, we cannot have, for example, $x_1=x_3$. This is what $x_j$'s distinct means